# How can I paste text without format in Lync's chat window?

Tags: text-formatting, lync, skype-for-business, paste

Is there any way to disable the paste-with-format feature on Lync? I'd like to paste only the text instead of having something like this:

[image: paste with format in Lync]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> to paste without formatting.

Comment: That is stripping some annoying formatting such as bullet points, but keeping colour and font.  I don't know where all this crap about pasting the source formatting came from - does anyone really want to do that by default?

Comment: When I use C-A-v it strips color and font as well. Not sure why your lync behaves differently..

Comment: My Lync pastes nothing...

Comment: @dunxd, Aw, I love it when I get light gray on white text pasted in Lync. Makes my chats look extra professional.

Comment: In Skype for Business, it's Ctrl+Shift+V now.

Comment: @Noumenon: it doesn't work in `Skype for Business for Office 365 MSO (16.0.11328.2586) 32-bit` for me.

Comment: @saulius2 Thanks for comparing, I should have provided a version number myself. My comment applies to `Skype for Business 2016 (16.0.4978.1000)`.

Answer (score 6):

Copy and paste it to notepad or another plain text editor.

Copy it from notepad into your target application, Lync in this case.

Comment: Seems this is the only option. I would prefer this to be an option in Lynch though... Both as a global option to use source text styles, and as a local function to paste as plain text directly in the chat window.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/) or other similar utilities. I use it and it works with Lync flawlessly. By default it allows to convert'n'paste text by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, but seems like it can override <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> too.

Answer (score 2):

I use [ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/) as a clipboard tool, and when I paste from its menu (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>) it pastes plain text.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to paste into Lync/Skype without formatting. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> does not work in newer versions.

The only keyboard shortcut to paste without formatting would be: <kbd>Win</kbd>, "note", <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, move cursor to Skype window, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: so complex. in newer Skype for business you just need to use `Ctrl+Shift+V`

Comment: @phuclv: it doesn't in Skype for Business for Office 365 MSI (16.0.11328.2586) 32-bit

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> doesn't work for me in Skype for business 2016. However <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> works gracefully

Or you can simply press <kbd>Menu</kbd> button (the key between right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and right <kbd>Windows</kbd>) then <kbd>N</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

On my Dell Latitude laptop there is no <kbd>right Windows</kbd> key. However there is the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key on my full keyboard and the symbol for it is a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key for the <kbd>right Ctrl</kbd> key, or you can get that by right-clicking in the Skype window then either select paste unformatted from the pop-up options, or press the 'n' key which I find even faster than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>!